# Unity3d android plugin capabilities

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have little experience with Unity3d and checking my possibilities:

Say i write android plugin for unity

My requirements:

1. Display different android layouts with WebView which run html-5.
2. Run android activities while using png assets
3. Intercept android device UI touches

Is this something that can be implemented in unity as an android plugin?

Thanks for the help

Comment: there is something discussed here http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html.

Comment: still what i want to know is how do i use a library project which depends on different other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your requirements, I suppose that you'd like to create native Ads or something like that which is perfectly doable.

1. It is possible to pause Unity Game and display another activity. It's also possible to show WebView as this activity.
2. I don't understand this fully but I guess you wanted to use PNG assets and display them. If I'm correct then yes, it's possible, you can bundle PNG assets as resources and them bundle into JAR.
3. UI Touches are collected by activity that is currently being displayed.